# GCC - Truncation due to type conversion warning

Tags: gcc, arm, gcc-warning

Why is the compiler not throwing a value truncation due to the conversion from a uint32 to a uint8 variable type? Precisely the line `result = reg_value;`

```
void read_byte_register(uint32_t u32_address_rd_byte_reg,
        uint8_t *pu8_Data_rd_byte_reg)
{
    uint8_t result;
    uint32_t reg_value;
    uint32_t *reg_ptr;

    reg_ptr = (uint32_t *) u32_address_rd_byte_reg;

    reg_value = *(reg_ptr);

    result = reg_value;

    *(pu8_Data_rd_byte_reg) = result;
}
```

The build command. You can see it is building for an ARM Cortex M3:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  -g3 -T "linker_script.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"output_map.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "output.elf"
```

Comment: I don't see any warning flags.

Comment: @StephenNewell Edited. Tried with the flags -pedantic -Wall -Wextra and still no warning

Comment: I get no warning with your flags. Please include the exact compiler warnings you are getting. Copying your code, adding `#include <stdint.h>` to it, and compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc 11.2.0 with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  -g3 -c file.c` results in no warnings. Please include all the warnings, and _if you use -Wconversion_, please include it, and please add the exact error message.

Comment: @KamilCuk Added -Wconversion showed the warning. I initially thought they were shown by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the flag `-Wconversion` as stated in a comment to the question fixed the problem. Apparently it is disabled by default. `-Wconversion` enables warnings about implicit type conversions. Attaching a screenshot about the warning:

[image]

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -g3 -T "linker_script.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"output_map.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "output.elf"
```